# How to add values into an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

If I want to add values to an array in a while loop I could do `$arr[] = "some"`. But how can I do this if I have an associative array, for example:

```
while($result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
   $arr[]["some_key"] = "some";
   $arr[]["other_key"] = "some2";
}
```

But this will give me something like `Array ( [0] => Array ( [some_key] => some) [1] => Array ( [other_key] => some2)`. So what is the right way to add values into an associative array inside a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary array for your keys, and then push that temporary array onto the main one:

```
$arr = [];
loop(condition) {
    $tmp = [];
    $tmp['some_key'] = 'some value';
    $tmp['other_key'] = 'other value';
    $arr[] = $tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not overwrite your values:

```
$arr = array();
while($result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($result as $key=>$value)
    {        
       $tmp[$key] = $value;  
    }
    $arr[]=$tmp;
}
```

Or more succinctly:

```
$arr = array();
while($result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $arr[]=$result;
}
```

Since PHP defaults to copying rather than referencing.

If you wanted to store them as an assoc. array of arrays you might do this:

```
$arr = array();
while($result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    foreach($result as $key=>$value)
    {        
       if(!isset($arr[$key])){
         $arr[$key] = array();
       }
       $arr[$key][] = $value;  
    }
}
```